# Devise + SignUp-SignIn using mobile number only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails API, trying to register the User via Mobile Number Only, and I have to keep the EMAIL column for promotion and communication.

In API, only I want to pass the mobile number and role of the User because Andriod App is already validating the mobile number through Twilio API.

As per requirement, If the User verifies the mobile number, the Application should register the User-based on the mobile number.

Getting Error `Email can't be blank`

Model : `User.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  attr_accessor :login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :telephone
  #validates :email, presence: false

  def login
    @login || self.telephone || self.email
  end

  def email_required?
    false
  end
end
```

Controller: RegistrationController

```
class Api::V1::Users::RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController
  include DeviseTokenAuthResponseSerializer
  prepend_before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(
      :sign_up,
      keys: %i(telephone first_name last_name date_of_birth)
    )
  end
end
```

Errors:

```
"errors": {
  "email": [
    "can't be blank"
  ],
  "full_messages": [
    "Email can't be blank"
  ]
}
```

Commented everything related with email in devise.rb

Removed indexing of Email from migration too. Still not working

Comment: the wiki has the answer https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address

Comment: you're using `devise_token_auth`, right ? (because i see `DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController`). i think that gem is the cause.

Comment: note that `devise` gem create `resource`(user) allow `email` field empty, meanwhile `devise_token_auth` does not, you can compare migrations be generated by 2 gems to see that. beside that, `devise_token_auth` gem actually already set `email_required? false` (also disable 2 another email validations).

Comment: @LamPhan - I cnt remove the existing functionality, so I am putting a dummy email to bypass this issue,  but while login - even though credentials are right, always getting unauthorized

Comment: oh, if you're finding a workaround, i have an idea, first you make your app work with normal case (with normal email) for sure, then you can apply authentication with phone number with emails format like  `phone-number@gmail.com`, so in view you get phone number but when call authen method, you transform phone to email like that, i know, that's ugly but interesting ha ha

Comment: @LamPhan - thanks for same idea :P - already doing the same way but the login fails. When I check valid password method, it says true.

Comment: have you read the link given by @Clara? it have steps that (i believe) you didn't do ,judging from your code, like `config.authentication_keys = [:telephone]` on the initializer

Comment: @blackbiron - Yes already followed the steps mentioned by Clara, Signup is working but SignIn failing.